# Vuex: Handle root action in namespaced module that is dispatched from another namespaced module

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Vue 2.3.4

I have >2 namespaced Vuex modules. The first is a Datepicker module stores daterange states. The other modules need to know when the dateranges change. So my intent is for multiple modules to "listen" to a single dispatched `datesChanged` event.

Datepicker (:

```
namespaced: true,
actions: {
   setDates ({ dispatch, commit }, dates) {
      // do stuff
      dispatch('datesChanged', dates, { root: true });
   }
}
```

ModuleX, ModuleY, ModuleZ...

```
namespaced: true,
actions: {
    datesChanged: {
        root: true,
        handler({ dispatch }, dates) {
            console.log('moduleX datesChanged', dates);
        }
    }
}
```

According to this: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#accessing-global-assets-in-namespaced-modules I'm doing it right..., but I keep getting this error: `unknown action type: datesChanged`.

I'm very new to Vue, but what I have here makes sense (to me at least). What am I missing? It seems like Vuex isn't registering my `datesChanged` handler at the root level.

(Edit: clarified intent)

Comment: My bad, I overlooked that you had defined the `datesChanged` action with `root: true`. In that case, your code should be working: https://jsfiddle.net/pb928o7q/. So, if you're getting the "unknown action type" message, then it's being caused by something you haven't shared.

Comment: @thanksd Your jsfiddle did help because I realized that a) I was doing it correctly, and b) My vuex version was out of date!! Updated to latest and bam!